# How do I call a function on all hyperlinks on my page?

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

I have a web page with multiple hyperlinks.  They all have an `href` of "`#`".  They are dynamically generated. How do I call a function when ANY of them are clicked? I wish to preserve default hyperlink actions.

Comment: How are they generated? What do you mean _preserving hyperlink action_? Is the `href` exactly `#` or do you have page anchors? (eg `#section1`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [event delegation](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/06/30/event-delegation-in-javascript/)

```
window.onload = function () {
  document.body.onclick = function (e) {
    var target = e.target,  
        isLink = target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'a';

    if (isLink && target.getAttribute('href') === '#') {
      lickFun(e); 
    }
  };

  function lickFun(e) {
      console.log('this is link');
      console.log('href equals #');         
  }
}
```

[`Example`](http://jsbin.com/dacimu/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: This is the one that worked for me. Thank you for that. Thank you to everybody.

Answer (score 0):

This can easily ve done in just plain ol' vanilla JavaScript.  Here's how.

1. Use `document.querySelectorAll("a[href='#']` to select all the links that have an `href` of "`#`".
2. Use a `for` loop to loop through all of the links.
3. Add an event listener to all of the links.  Simply like this (this snippet includes dynamically generated links):

```js
document.body.innerHTML = '<a href="#">Click me to call a function.</a><br/>' +
'<a href="#">Click me to call the same function.<\/a><br/>' +
'<a href="#">Click me to call the same function.<\/a><br/>' +
'<a href="#">Click me to call the same function.<\/a><br/>' +
'<a href="#">Click me to call the same function.<\/a><br/>' +
'<a href="http://www.cnn.com">My "href" is not "#".<\/a><br/>' +
'<a href="http://espn.go.com">Neither is mine.<\/a>'

var linkListener = document.querySelectorAll("a[href='#']");

for (i=0;i<linkListener.length;i++){
  linkListener[i].addEventListener("click", linkFunction);
  }

function linkFunction(){
  
  alert("You clicked a link with an \"href\" of \"#\".");
  
  }
```

Clicking any of the links that have an `href` of "`#`" will call the `linkFunction`.

Comment: This approach does not work if content was added dynamically, see example http://jsbin.com/dacimu/2/edit

Comment: It CAN work with dynamically generated content if you set it up correctly, @Alexander.  In your jsbin, you have it set up in a way in which it does not work.

Comment: Could you update jsbin ?

Comment: I updated my answer with dynamically generated links.

Comment: Still does not work http://jsbin.com/geniya/1/edit?js,output

Comment: Or main idea always execute your code after add content dynamically ?

Comment: Yes, run the code after the content is added.

Answer (score -1):

if you are using jquery you can do that like this:

```
<a href="http://google.com">google</a>
<a href="#">test1</a>
<a href="#">test2</a>
<a href="#">test3</a>
<script>
        $('a[href="#"]').bind('click',function(){
            alert("Test");
        })
</script>
```